# Trying to import a sample project, but every import has the following error import name cannot be resolved

Tags: android

I'm trying to learn NFC and download the sample project at
http://www.framentos.com/en/android-tutorial/2012/07/31/write-hello-world-into-a-nfc-tag-with-a/

I selected import from the file menu then choose existing project into workspace and select the corresponding zip file.

The new project appeared in my eclipse workspace and all the files where there, but on the source file it had a error for every import saying  import name cannot be resolved, example
import java.io cannot be resolved.

I have the source code below, but I'm assuming its some setting in eclipse?

```
package com.framentos.hellonfc;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.nfc.FormatException;
import android.nfc.NdefMessage;
import android.nfc.NdefRecord;
import android.nfc.NfcAdapter;
import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.nfc.tech.Ndef;
import android.nfc.tech.NdefFormatable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


@SuppressLint({ "ParserError", "ParserError" })
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

NfcAdapter adapter;
PendingIntent pendingIntent;
IntentFilter writeTagFilters[];
boolean writeMode;
Tag mytag;
Context ctx;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ctx=this;
    Button btnWrite = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    final TextView message = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.edit_message);

    btnWrite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                if(mytag==null){
                    Toast.makeText(ctx, ctx.getString(R.string.error_detected), Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                }else{
                    write(message.getText().toString(),mytag);
                    Toast.makeText(ctx, ctx.getString(R.string.ok_writing), Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(ctx, ctx.getString(R.string.error_writing), Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (FormatException e) {
                Toast.makeText(ctx, ctx.getString(R.string.error_writing) , Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    adapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
    IntentFilter tagDetected = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED);
    tagDetected.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    writeTagFilters = new IntentFilter[] { tagDetected };

}



private void write(String text, Tag tag) throws IOException, FormatException {

    NdefRecord[] records = { createRecord(text) };
    NdefMessage  message = new NdefMessage(records);
    // Get an instance of Ndef for the tag.
    Ndef ndef = Ndef.get(tag);
    // Enable I/O
    ndef.connect();
    // Write the message
    ndef.writeNdefMessage(message);
    // Close the connection
    ndef.close();
}



private NdefRecord createRecord(String text) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String lang       = "en";
    byte[] textBytes  = text.getBytes();
    byte[] langBytes  = lang.getBytes("US-ASCII");
    int    langLength = langBytes.length;
    int    textLength = textBytes.length;
    byte[] payload    = new byte[1 + langLength + textLength];

    // set status byte (see NDEF spec for actual bits)
    payload[0] = (byte) langLength;

    // copy langbytes and textbytes into payload
    System.arraycopy(langBytes, 0, payload, 1,              langLength);
    System.arraycopy(textBytes, 0, payload, 1 + langLength, textLength);

    NdefRecord recordNFC = new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_WELL_KNOWN,  NdefRecord.RTD_TEXT,  new byte[0], payload);

    return recordNFC;
}


@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent){
    if(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())){
        mytag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);    
        Toast.makeText(this, this.getString(R.string.ok_detection) + mytag.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    WriteModeOff();
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    WriteModeOn();
}

private void WriteModeOn(){
    writeMode = true;
    adapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, writeTagFilters, null);
}

private void WriteModeOff(){
    writeMode = false;
    adapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
}


}
```

Comment: I'm assuming that you have included the Android libraries in your build path and that you have selected an Android SDK in the project preferences?

Comment: Have your tried unzipping before importing?

Comment: Thank you Gibson, I thought all I add to do was import and it would do the res,  I selected a android sdk in prefence and all the errors went away